# Assigning value to a list and transforming data in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, dataframe, transform

I am new to Python and struggling with some basic transformations (yikes!)

I want to write code that will open an excel workbook with IDs and Locations and run every line through a function that maps said location to a code (**note that I don't want to merge all at once, every line needs to run through the function individually**):

[Desired Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLfdf.png)

So far I have managed to write the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

ids = "IDs.xlsx"
df_IDs = pd.read_excel(ids)

codes = "MAP.xlsx"
df_codes = pd.read_excel(codes)

def prop_id(location):
    datapoints = [[location, "Yes"]]
    df = pd.DataFrame(datapoints, columns=['Location', 'Is Match'])
    merge = pd.merge(df_codes, df, how='left', left_on='Location', right_on='Location')
    fltr = merge.dropna()
    column = fltr[['Code']]
    output = column.values.tolist()
    return output

df_IDs['PlaceID'] = df_IDs['Location'].apply(prop_id)
print(df_IDs)
```

This outputs the following:

```
   ID    Property    Location          PlaceID
0  1234  Property A  Location 1  [[A], [E], [F]]
1  1235  Property B  Location 2            [[B]]
```

What I am trying to accomplish then is to map the ID column to every list value in the PlaceID column and to turn the data vertical. In other words:

```
   ID    Property    Location     PlaceID
0  1234  Property A  Location 1   A
1  1234  Property A  Location 1   E         
1  1234  Property A  Location 1   F
1  1235  Property B  Location 2   B
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!